# Proof of basic arithmetic operations

Tags: number-theory

I'm interested in knowing the proofs for the basic arithmetic operations, just for fun. I suppose some like the addition of positive numbers will be axiomatic but I would like to know the proofs or be guided to a place where I can find the proofs to not so obvious operations like the product of two negative numbers being positive and the like.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Arithmetic.

Comment: See my recent answer on proving 2+2=4 at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842314/prove-that-22-4/843213#843213

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially you want to use the field axioms; I'll leave the wikipediaing up to you.

---

Idea: First prove you have "cancellation," and then prove things like the following.

Given that $0 = 0 + 0$, note that for any real number $x$, we have (using the distributive law):

$x(0) + x(0) = x(0 + 0) = x(0)$; now cancel $x(0)$ from both sides to conclude $x(0) = 0$.

Similarly (or just using commutativity for multiplication of real numbers) we have $0x = 0$.

---

An example using the property above:

$(-3)(5) + 15 = (-3)(5) + (3)(5) = (-3 + 3)(5) = 0(5) = 0$, whence $(-3)(5) = -15$.

I just used $-3$ and $5$ for fun; really this can demonstrate negative * positive = negative.

---

Another property:

$15 + (-15) = 0$, so that $15 = -(-15)$.

This is close to the idea that negative * negative = positive; in fact we can now proceed as follows:

$(-3)(-5) + (-15) = (-3)(-5) + (-3)(5) = (-3)(-5 + 5) = (-3)(0) = 0$.

Again, we conclude from the above that $(-3)(-5) = -(-15) = 15$, and can generalize this method to prove that negative * negative = positive.

Answer (score 3):

In this question, like in all questions about the most fundamental properties of mathematics, you run into the question of

1. how much detail you want in the proof, and
2. what you can take for
   granted in the proof.

Regarding 1), the problem is that when a something is totally trivial, the only thing you can really do to make the proof more formal is to write down the proof in first-order logic and deduce everything from ZFC, which is quite tedious and not very interesting. Alternatively, you may do a relatively superficial proof like I do below, which will probably disappoint you a bit, since it does not really seem any closer to the rigour that you most likely want in this situation. Regarding 2), you need to be well aware of exactly how you have chosen to define numbers and the like in terms of set theory. It is important to note that there will always be more than one model for a give set of axioms and hence several, equivalent ways to introduce a given mathematical object. Which one you use is usually not something that has practical consequences.

I shall not go into details with the construction of the natural numbers, as this can be found in the link to the article about the Peano Axioms. We therefore take $\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ for granted along with its addition and multiplication operations. We define $\Bbb Z$ to be the set $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N/\sim_{\Bbb Z}$ of equivalence classes of $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ with respect to the equivalence relation $\sim_{\Bbb Z}$ given by
$$
(x,y)\sim_{\Bbb Z}(x',y')\iff x+y'=x'+y
$$
for all $(x,y),(x',y')\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$. Now we write $x-y$ for the equivalence class $[(x,y)]$ of $(x,y)$ with respect to $\sim_{\Bbb Z}$. We identify $x\in\Bbb N$ with $x-0$ and define $-x := 0-x$. We define addition by
$$
(x-y)+(x'-y')=(x+x')-(y+y')
$$
and multiplication by
$$
(x-y)\cdot(x'-y') = xx'+yy'-(x'y+xy'),
$$
where all operations on the $x,y,x',y'$ are those from $\Bbb N$. It is not hard to prove that these operations are well-defined and extend the addition and multiplication of $\Bbb N$. Now for your question regarding the product of negative numbers, we have
$$
(-y)\cdot(-y') = (0-y)\cdot(0-y') = yy'
$$
by our definition of multiplication. Thus the property that "minus minus is plus" follows directly from our definition of multiplication.

We have hence only proved the property for $\Bbb Z$, but can carry it on to $\Bbb {Q, R,C}$ by doing similar considerations regarding their definitions: $\Bbb Q$ is the set $\Bbb Z\times(\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\})/\sim_{\Bbb Q}$ of equivalence classes of $\Bbb Z\times(\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\})$ with respect to the equivalence class $\sim_{\Bbb Q}$ given by
$$
(x,y)\sim_{\Bbb Q}(x',y')\iff xy'=x'y
$$
for all $(x,y),(x',y')\in\Bbb Z\times(\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\})$. We write $x/y$ for the equivalence class of $(x,y)$ with respect to $\sim_{\Bbb Q}$. We define
$$
\frac x y+\frac{x'}{y'} := \frac{xy'+x'y}{yy'}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac x y\cdot\frac{x'}{y'} := \frac{xx'}{yy'}
$$
and check that they are well-defined and satisfy appropriate properties, including that $x\in\Bbb Z$ can be identified with $x/1\in\Bbb Q$. We then check directly that "minus times minus is minus".

Finally, we define $\Bbb R$ to be the set of Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb Q$ divided by the equivalence class $\sim_{\Bbb R}$ given by
$$
\{a_n\}\sim_{\Bbb R}\{b_n\}\iff \forall\varepsilon > 0\quad\exists N\in\Bbb N\quad\forall n\ge N\colon \lvert a_n - b_n\rvert < \varepsilon,
$$
meaning that $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ "should have the same limit". Now $x\in\Bbb Q$ is identified with the class of sequences that have limit $x$, and we define addition and multiplication by
$$
[\{a_n\}]+[\{b_n\}] := [\{a_n+b_n\}]
\quad\text{and}\quad
[\{a_n\}]\cdot[\{b_n\}] := [\{a_n b_n\}],
$$
and blah blah blah. Now the property that "minus times minus is plus" is carried over from $\Bbb Q$.

I leave it to you to check that the property is also true in $\Bbb C$.